# Creating directory tree based on file name

Tags: shell-script, command-line, files, osx, directory

I have a large number of files with the following structure:

```
[Lion] 2015 Africa Book.pdf
[Lion] 2015 Africa Magazine.pdf
[Lion] 2016 Africa Book.pdf
[Lion] 2016 Africa Magazine.pdf
[Lion] 2015 Asia Book.pdf
[Lion] 2015 Asia Magazine.pdf
[Lion] 2016 Asia Book.pdf
[Lion] 2016 Asia Magazine.pdf
[Tiger] 2016 Africa Book.pdf
[Tiger] 2016 Africa Magazine.pdf
[Tiger] 2015 Asia Book.pdf
[Tiger] 2015 Asia Magazine.pdf
[Tiger] 2016 Asia Book.pdf
[Tiger] 2016 Asia Magazine.pdf
```

etc.

basically the files follow the follwoing pattern: `[{animal}] {year} {location} {format}.{ext}`

How can I move the file so they have a directory stucture like this?

```
Animal stuff
├── Lion
│   ├── 2015 - Africa
│   │   ├── [Lion] 2015 Africa Book.pdf
│   │   └── [Lion] 2015 Africa Magazine.pdf
│   ├── 2015 - Asia
│   │   ├── [Lion] 2015 Asia Book.pdf
│   │   └── [Lion] 2015 Asia Magazine.pdf
│   ├── 2016 - Africa
│   │   ├── [Lion] 2016 Africa Book.pdf
│   │   └── [Lion] 2016 Africa Magazine.pdf
│   └── 2016 - Asia
│       ├── [Lion] 2016 Asia Book.pdf
│       └── [Lion] 2016 Asia Magazine.pdf
└── Tiger
    ├── 2015 - Africa
    │   ├── [Tiger] 2015 Africa Book.pdf
    │   └── [Tiger] 2015 Africa Magazine.pdf
    ├── 2015 - Asia
    │   ├── [Tiger] 2015 Asia Book.pdf
    │   └── [Tiger] 2015 Asia Magazine.pdf
    ├── 2016 - Africa
    │   ├── [Tiger] 2016 Africa Book.pdf
    │   └── [Tiger] 2016 Africa Magazine.pdf
    └── 2016 - Asia
        ├── [Tiger] 2016 Asia Book.pdf
        └── [Tiger] 2016 Asia Magazine.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c '
    animal=${1%% *}; 
    year=${1#* }; year=${year% *};
    mkdir -p "${animal//[][]}/${year/ / - }" && mv "$animal $year"'*' "${animal//[][]}/${year/ / - }/"
' _ {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

result:

```
$ tree
.
├── Lion
│   ├── 2015 - Africa
│   │   ├── [Lion] 2015 Africa Book.pdf
│   │   └── [Lion] 2015 Africa Magazine.pdf
│   ├── 2015 - Asia
│   │   ├── [Lion] 2015 Asia Book.pdf
│   │   └── [Lion] 2015 Asia Magazine.pdf
│   ├── 2016 - Africa
│   │   ├── [Lion] 2016 Africa Book.pdf
│   │   └── [Lion] 2016 Africa Magazine.pdf
│   └── 2016 - Asia
│       ├── [Lion] 2016 Asia Book.pdf
│       └── [Lion] 2016 Asia Magazine.pdf
└── Tiger
    ├── 2015 - Asia
    │   ├── [Tiger] 2015 Asia Book.pdf
    │   └── [Tiger] 2015 Asia Magazine.pdf
    ├── 2016 - Africa
    │   ├── [Tiger] 2016 Africa Book.pdf
    │   └── [Tiger] 2016 Africa Magazine.pdf
    └── 2016 - Asia
        ├── [Tiger] 2016 Asia Book.pdf
        └── [Tiger] 2016 Asia Magazine.pdf
```

Comment: It mostly works, but it but the `book` and `magazine` files in separate directories. I want them to be in the same directory.

Comment: Just fyi, `find -maxdepth` sould be `find . -maxdepth`. At least that;s what I have to do on my computer. Btw thanks for the help

Comment: @αғsнιη The point (i.e. a path) is optional on GNU's `find`. Other systems (for instance MacOS) require an explicit path.

Comment: ohhh, I don't know mac os, sry